# macbook pro retina overheating

Tags: kubuntu, macbook, overheating

I've strange problem that I have tried to solve for long time

Macbook Pro Retina overheating

I've tried : laptop-mode-tools,indicator-cpu,thermald,powertop

Distros tried to use but no fix : Ubuntu 16.04 , Kubuntu 16.04 , Arch , Debian jessie , Fedora 23 - 24

the only Distro that I managed to get cool temperature with it was Kubuntu 14.04 which worked very good

I tried to research whats causing the overheat , I installed lm-sensors and ran sensors-detect and then sensors and I got interesting thing:

with every distro that I tried with no luck I got , TH0c : -127.0 C.

and the only distro that worked for me Kubuntu 14.04 when I ran sensors there is No TH0c , can this be the problem ? and why I got this sensor on all the distros and the only distro that didn't have TH0c it worked perfectly ? if this is really the problem how to fix that ?

Comment: What is the GPU there?

Answer (score 1):

This is what i did to get the Macbook fans to work properly you will need to enable the Mactel PPA and install macfanctld.

`sudo add-apt-repository ppa:mactel-support/ppa
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install macfanctld`

For more info you can read with more details in here, this is where i found my solution https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MacBookPro6-2/Precise

Comment: I got this error: Reading package lists... Done                                                  
E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/mactel-support/ppa/ubuntu bionic Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.